# Activity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks

Tags: java, android, google-api

I am calling checkLocationOn method from another class as

```
 // Change Address Click Action
    tvProfileChangeAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if ((checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    GetLocation.checkLocationOn(Profile.this);
                }else{
                    AskPermissions.AskLocationPermission(Profile.this);
                }
              } else {
                GetLocation.checkLocationOn(Profile.this);
            }
            }
        });
```

I have Initialized My GoogleApiClient in CheckLocation method.

```
 // Building Google API Client
protected static synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(Context context){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) context)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) context)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    createLocationRequest();
    return;

}
```

while Initializing GoogleApiClient my Application force stops giving error

> 03-27 16:43:13.930 5118-5118/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.demo.FetchLocation, PID: 5118
>                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.demo.FetchLocation.Profile cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks
>                                                        at com.demo.FetchLocation.GetLocation.buildGoogleApiClient(GetLocation.java:75)
>                                                        at com.demo.FetchLocation.GetLocation.checkLocationOn(GetLocation.java:68)
>                                                        at com.demo.FetchLocation.Profile$2.onClick(Profile.java:128)
>                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269)
>                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Does anyone have solution for this ??

Comment: post full stack trace

Comment: Is `Profile` class an Activity?

Comment: yess Profile is an Activity

Comment: Post code of `Profile` activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `Profile` activity implemented both `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` interfaces.

When you're executing following,

```
.addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) context)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) context)
```

you don't actually have implemented any of those Interfaces in your passed context, which in your case, belongs to Profile activity.

Comment: Thank You !! That Works ... I forgot to implement those in profile Activity

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), the right method call is:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected static synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(Context context){
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
createLocationRequest();
return;

}
```

write this and implement all methods of the interfaces you are implementing in your acctivity.